# How to execute any step n number of times

Tags: jbehave

Although I am able to run any story n number of times using JBehave, I want to execute a step n number of times. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. Try configuring your runner class to create your n steps instances and run n story files associated.